# Is it true that $A[x] \subseteq B[x] \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative rings and suppose that $A[x] \subseteq B[x]$.

Is it true that $A \subseteq B \space$?

Comment: What is your exact definition of $A[x]$ as a set?

Comment: $A[x]$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients in $A$ and indeterminate $x$

Comment: Is $A[x][x]=A[x]$?

Comment: My point is that "$A[x]\subseteq B[x]$" is a highly unnatural statement, since normally it is not very meaningful to talk about elements from two totally unrelated sets being equal.  To make it meaningful, you have to therefore give some precise set-theoretic definition of what the set $A[x]$ is (or otherwise explain what you mean).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you can clarify your question.

Let $A=\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $B=\mathbb{R}$.  Then $A[x]=A$ and $B[x]=A$.  In this case, $A[x]\subseteq B[x]$, but $A\not\subseteq B$.

Therefore, if you allow your indeterminate to be part of your rings, the statement is false.  If $x$ is transcendental over $A$ and $B$ and the inclusion $A[x]\subseteq B[x]$ respects grading, then your statement should be correct.

Comment: "If you allow your indeterminate to be part of your rings" then it isn't an indeterminate.

Comment: You've essentially confused two notations. When $\alpha\in S$ and $R$ is a subring of $S$, then $R[\alpha]$ means one thing. When $x$ is an indeterminate, then $R[x]$ means another thing. Using these two notations together is sure to fail. In particular, $R[x][x]$ is obviously deeply confused - a bit like defining $f(x)=\int_{0}^x g(x)\,dx$.

Comment: The two notations can be merged.  In general, $R[x]$ means the set of finite sums or powers of $x$ with coefficients in $R$.  Then, one can consider relations between the elements.  If one wanted to be more pedantic, $R[x][x]$ could be written as $R[x][y]/(x-y)$.

Comment: Are you asking if there is an injective homomorphism $f:A[x]\to B[x]$ with $f(x)=x$, then, $f(a)\in B$ for all $a\in A$? This is of course false. For example, take $A=k[z], B=k[y]$ and consider $f$ a $k$-algebra homomorphism with $f(z)=y+x, f(x)=x$.

Comment: Except this means $R[x]$ means different things whether there is a thing called $x$ in $R$. That seems like dangerous notation. I'd rather take $R[x]$ to always mean adding an indeterminate, so $R[x][x]\cong R[x,y]$.

Comment: @Mohan If you want clarification for the question, put your comment on the question. The OP won't be notified here.

Comment: Finally, $R[x][y]/\langle x-y\rangle$ is a meaning to notation without a purpose. There is no need to discuss $S[\alpha]$ when $\alpha\in S$ - it is always $\alpha$. (You could need $R[x^2][x]\cong R[x]$, for example, which can be thought of as $R[y][x]/(y-x^2)$.)